# Java outputs a Full Thread Dump every few seconds when running from IntelliJ and given network sniffing permissions with setcap

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, dump

I am writing an application that does packet sniffing using a Pcap library. For that to work, I need to give the `java` binary network sniffing capabilities to avoid having to run it as `root`:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /path/to/bin/java
```

When I run any program, every few seconds, I get a Full Thread Dump to `stdout`. [Here](https://gitlab.com/Alfred456654/test-pcap/-/raw/master/bad_output.txt) is an example of such a full thread dump (the rest of the repo is irrelevant). The program otherwise seems to run successfully: except for the dump, I couldn't find a difference in the execution.

The code below is sufficient to reproduce the issue:

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;

public class StdinTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

When I remove the capabilities from the `java` binary with the command below, things go back to normal and I no longer get the Full Thread Dumps to stdout.

```
sudo setcap -r /path/to/bin/java
```

I'm not sure it's a problem since the program seems to run fine, but it doesn't look *normal*.

I haven't found anyone who seems to have a similar issue, I'm a bit lost...

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

Details:

- OS: reproduced on ArchLinux (kernel 5.12.9) & Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.8.0)
- JDK: reproduced on Adopt OpenJDK 11, 15 & 16, openjdk.java.net 15 & 16.

---

**EDIT**:

Not reproduceable if the program is ran in command line:

```
java -classpath target/classes main.StdinTest
```

I only get the symptoms when starting it from IntelliJ Idea Ultimate. I haven't tried with other IDEs.

Comment: IDEA prints the exact command line it uses to start Java processes at the beginning of the output. Did you check if any of the arguments it uses can help you reproduce the issue? For example I'm pretty sure they add an agent of theirs to the JVM.

Comment: Weirdly enough, it adds plenty of python to the classpath... I pasted it here:
https://gist.github.com/giraudan/466cf36c1605174e0bb5b99be7bb2922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If intelliJ thinks your software is stuck, it will take thread dumps from it. `System.in.read();` makes it "stuck" on reading from stdin.

You should be able to disable it using `-Dperformance.watcher.unresponsive.interval.ms=0` in [VM options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869).
The recommended way of changing the JVM options is via the `Help | Edit Custom VM Options` action.

Reference: [intellij support: Disable "Automatic thread dumps"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000105710-Disable-Automatic-thread-dumps-).

Comment: I added that option to my IDE's VM options, restarted it just in case, but it didn't change the problem. To be extra-sure, I also added it in my `idea.properties` file.

Thank you for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 3):

I also posted my question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/nu6quj/full_thread_dump_every_few_seconds_when_java_is/) and someone suggested that such full thread dumps are displayed when the process receives a signal 3.

I was unable to detect that signal being sent to it by using `strace`, but I did notice that running the code in command line rather than inside my IDE solved the issue.

I also tried sending a signal 3 to the program running in command line, and it does display the same full thread dump.

Kind of unsatisfactory ending, I'm not 100% sure what's happening, but I'm getting confident that this is a non-issue that I can ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you add the following in **Help** | **Edit Custom Properties** and restart the IDE?

```
debugger.attach.to.process.action=false
execution.dump.threads.using.attach=false
```

From: [Intellij keeps dumping threads when running simplest application with openjdk 11](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-267651)